# How to authenticate a website user through iphone

Tags: iphone, authentication

I have created a web application and now I want to create an iPhone version of it. As a first step, I want to login a user using his username and password. I have a simple login page with fields for username and password. Now I want to send these credentials onto my site (lets say, www.abc.com/login) and authenticate whether the username and password is correct or not.

I need some help in this as I am not an experienced iphone developer. I just need to know how to send the credentials to my site url.
Any help or sample tutorial in this regard will be highly helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

Go get [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) as it is a great framework for any network connectivity you do.  the you can simply use POST or use the method they have provided for authentication.

See the section titled "Handling Authentication" [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for code samples and docs

Answer (score 0):

better make a canvas and call that page of webapplication..